# Vaadin app returns error (403) Forbidden on start

Tags: undertow, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin 14 application running on the Undertow server, all wrapped in a single fatjar as an embedded application. Without SpringBoot, because I have limited memory and any MB counts! It worked for me up to Vaadin version 14.5 without any problem, since version 14.6 I get a 403 Forbidden error when loading the app in a browser.

My server startup code:

```java
final ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ServletContainerInitializerInfo initInfo =
   new ServletContainerInitializerInfo(RouteRegistryInitializer.class,setOfRouteAnnotatedClasses()) ;
ClassPathResourceManager resMgr =
   new ClassPathResourceManager(classLoader, "META-INF/resources");

DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = Servlets.deployment()
                    .setClassLoader(classLoader)
                    .setContextPath("/")
                    .setDeploymentName("cb200")
                    .setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .setResourceManager(resMgr)
                    .addServletContainerInitializer(info)
                    .addListener(Servlets.listener(ServletDeployer.class))
                    .addServletContextAttribute(WebSocketDeploymentInfo.ATTRIBUTE_NAME, wsdi);
DeploymentManager deploymentMgr = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(deploymentInfo);
deploymentMgr.deploy();

PathHandler path = path(redirect("/")).addPrefixPath("/", deploymentMgr.start()) ;

Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                    .addHttpListener(SERVER_PORT, SERVER_HOST)
                    .setHandler(path)
                    .build();
server.start();
```

I tracked down the problem to the `META-INF/resources` access. Because with Vaadin 14.5.x the server works fine, there must have been some change between Vaadin version 14.5 and 14.6 that causes a problem when Undertow accesses resources.

BTW I tried to run the app on Jetty server. Works ok, but the startup time of the application is more than 1 minute which is unacceptable.

Comment: The only bigger change in 14.6 would be the customTheme feature, but that shouldn't make any change if not used. Can you make a failing sample project from https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v14 so it could be looked into?

Comment: I created a project demonstrating the issue [here](https://github.com/envas/vaadin-starter-undertow-gradle). The project is based on the Vaadin starter skeleton.

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist - I think there were some changes regarding META-INF/resources handling, for example [issue #9405](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/9405).